# Another Venn problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We are to create a Venn Diagram for $B \cap A = A$. 
I have created this, I do not think this is correct. Can anyone shed some light on this?
[image: B intersect A = A]

Comment: In this case $A\cap B \neq A$. In general,  $A\cap B = A$ implies that $A\subset B$.

Comment: You can see how I typeset $B \cap A = A$ by right-clicking on the equation, then selecting Show Math As TeX Commands.  Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to have $B \cap A = A$, then there can be nothing in $A$ that is not also in $B$.
(i.e. circle $A$ should be entirely inside circle $B$)

The image you have is correct iff you interpret that region you shaded ($A \setminus B$) as being empty.

Comment: I thought that if they intersected  that it could not a complete intersection.

Comment: So Circle A should be in Circle B?

Comment: A diagram with $A$ completely inside $B$ is correct, but I don't know if it still qualifies as a Venn diagram.

Comment: A completely inside B?

Comment: @mapierce271 such a diagram is known as an Euler diagram.

Comment: How is this any different then the A U B = B? When i posted that question earlier, people responded by saying that the A is in the B also? How are any of these different?

Comment: $A \cup B = B \quad \iff \quad A \cap B = A$